# In rails, what is best practice for having_many items and having_one special item

Tags: ruby-on-rails, design-patterns, activerecord

In a rails application I have the following setup:

Projects has_many Pages.
Pages belong_to a Project.

Pages are created and edited using nested attributes on the Projects controller.

All editing is done using best_in_place where possible.

I now want to add the ability to have one default page for each project. After a long time of trying things, I came up with the solution of adding startpage_id to Projects, and adding

```
    belongs_to :startpage, class_name: "Page"
```

to the project model, since has_one was not working out. This seems unintuitive and I get the feeling that I am doing something wrong.

What would be the best practice in such a situation?

Comment: You are right about this being unintuitive. Why exactly did your `has_one` relation not work with the `start_page?`

Answer (score 0):

1. add a `startpage_id` field to your `Project` Model

   ```
   class AddStartpageFlagToPage < ActiveRecord::Migration
     def change
       add_column :projects, :startpage_id, :integer
     end
   end
   ```
2. write an instance methods:

   ```
   class Project
     ...
     def startpage
       Project.pages.find(startpage_id)
     end

     def startpage=(page)
       update_attribute(:startpage_id, page.id) if pages.include?(page)
     end
     ...
   end
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I would add a boolean field `startpage` to `Page` with a default value of `false`:

```
class AddStartpageFlagToPage < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :pages, :startpage, :boolean, default: false
  end
end
```

And add a method for finding the start page:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :pages

  def startpage
    pages.find_by(startpage: true)
  end
end
```

You might want to add validation ensuring that there's only one start page per project.